# How to manually merge files downloaded by IDM?

Tags: windows-8, download, merge, download-manager

For the last couple of days, I've been downloading an `.exe` file; its size is about *1.73 GB*. The **TEMP** folder was on `E:\`. When it's done, IDM merged about *1.5 GB*
 and gave me an error about no free space were left on `C:\` where the **OUTPUT** folder was located.

I freed up some space and resumed the process again. But it stuck in the middle and barely moved. So I cancelled it and retried. It then jumped to full par and stuck there. I force-closed it again. But the next time I resumed the download it went back to *15%*, meaning that it discarded about *1.5 GB* data.

But fortunately that part was merged in the **OUTPUT** folder. So I took the remaining *230 MB* part and put them together. Hoping that I might find a way to merge them and spare me the download again. Note that the whole program is fully downloaded but separated in two parts. I am using *Win 8*.

Comment: If you consider the answer below to be suitable, then please click the gray tick beside it.

Answer (score 4):

If the files TRULY are parts that make up a full download when merged, then the following should do the trick...

Open a CMD prompt:
hold the left Windows key, hit R, type `cmd` and hit Enter.

In the window that opens type:

```
cd  /d  drive:\path\to\the\files\
copy  /b name-part1  /b + name-part2  name-for-all-parts
exit
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works with video, the file is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Note: It depends entirely on what your download contained.

Comment: What is the job of  `\b`?

Comment: See the output of `copy /?`

Answer (score 0):

To manually combine the parts downloaded by IDM I like to use this command in CMD:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,amount_of_files) do type name_for_parts%i >> name_of_output
```

Replace `amount_of_files` with the amount of files you'd like to combine.

Replace `name_for_parts` with the name and extension of the files (without the number at the end). Don't remove the `%i` at the end!

Replace `name_for_output` with the name and extension of the file that gets created.

Example:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,8) do type video.mkv%i >> video.mkv
```

Comment: Are you sure this will combine binary data?

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes, this works on both text and binary files.